# How do I Toggle a divs height to make it appear as if it is sliding down?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, toggle

Please see this fiddle I have started.
http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/6bt70uhj/1/

```
$('#name-a').click(function() {
$('#bio-line-1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
$('#bio-line-2').animate({height: 'toggle'});
});
```

When you click the link the first sentence slides in from the left and the second line comes in from the first line. This is very close to what I am trying to achieve, however I need the second line to appear more like it is sliding as a whole object rather than looking like it is being revealed.

I have already tried using .SlideDown but this gave the same effect as .animate.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: you want the second line to slide like first one ??

Comment: No, I want the second line to slide downwards

Comment: OK, I got your point

Comment: Thanks @Satpal, thats helpful for the animating to start after the first is complete, but I still need the line to appear more as if it is moving downwards?

Comment: @Ankit, how do I animate the top property?

Comment: @Angela Is it fine... http://jsfiddle.net/6bt70uhj/5/

Comment: I have just updated the Fiddle, check now, its better http://jsfiddle.net/6bt70uhj/8/

Comment: Thanks, funnily enough I have just added the margin-top and adjusted the top value to make it better.

Comment: Perfect ! Just like your looks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:-

**css:**

```
#bio-line-2 {
left: 120px;
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
width: 433px;
z-index: 1;
margin-top:20px;

}
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#name-a').click(function() {
$('#bio-line-1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
$('#bio-line-2').animate({marginTop: 'toggle'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Could try this, If I understood your question properly

> ```
> $('#name-a').click(function() {
>     $('#bio-line-1').animate({width: 'toggle'});
>     window.setTimeout(function (){$('#bio-line-2').slideToggle( "slow" ); }, 300);
>   });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire line to slide as an object, its not the height you want to toggle, but rather the position relative to the element it should slide from. Your code would work if you'd just offset the element properly and then use:

```
 $('#bio-line-2').animate({marginTop: 'toggle'});
```

as Dipesh mentioned.

If you want to make sure the animation doesn't start before the first line has flown in from the left, you can pass in a function to execute after the first animation is finished, like so:

```
$('#bio-line-1').animate({width: 'toggle'},function(){ 

  $('#bio-line-2').animate({marginTop: 'toggle'});

});
```

This ensures the second animation waits for the first one to finish.